# Galileo's Feather-Coin experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Clearly Newton's law of gravitation asserts that earth (of mass $M$) attracts an object of mass $M_1$ by the force $GMM_1/r^2$, $r$ being the radius of the Earth. Thus a bigger mass $M_2$ would be attracted towards the earth with greater force, thus having more acceleration (neglecting air resistance). Then how does Galileo's Feather-Coin experiment work?

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thus a bigger mass $M_2$ would be attracted towards the earth with greater force.

It wouldn't. For a bigger mass, the force is bigger, but the force on particle 2 is related to its acceleration via Newton's second law, $$F=M_2a,$$ which means that a larger force is required for the same acceleration.

When you put everything together by equating $$\frac{GMM_2}{r^2}=M_2a,$$ the factors of $M_2$ cancel exactly and you get an expression for $a$ that's independent of $M_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In words, the explanation is that a larger mass does experience a larger force, as you say, but it also has larger inertia i.e. resistance to motion. As a result it doesn't have more acceleration and as @Emilio Pisanty has shown, the mass of the object drops out of the equation for its acceleration.